# How to get today start time and current time of EST using Moment.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, timezone, momentjs

I want to create Start and End Time stamp using Moment.js (EST):

- StartTime would be today's start time
- EndTime would be current time.

I have used moment.js and created like this

```
var time = new Date();
var startTime=Date.parse(moment(time).startOf('day').tz('America/New_York').format("MM/DD/YYYY HH:mm:ss"));
var endTime=Date.parse(moment(time).tz('America/New_York').format("MM/DD/YYYY HH:mm:ss"));
```

It is giving time in milliseconds.

Is it correct or wrong?

I am not getting data from db because there is mismatch in Time stamp.

Comment: why not use the Date object? I dont think you need moment for this.
What do you trying to do??

Comment: if I use Date object it will give current timezone time but I need only EST time zone so I am using moment.js

Comment: OK.. this is not reason not use date..

Answer (score 7):

First thing first, when you use momentjs, STOP using `Date` explictly:

```
var moment = require('moment-timezone');

// moment() without parameter means the current time
// toDate() converts the moment object to a javascript Date
var startTime = moment().tz('America/New_York').startOf('day').toDate();
var endTime = moment().tz('America/New_York').toDate();

// startTime and endTime are Date objects    
console.log(startTime);
console.log(endTime);
```