# Getting EST date in moment.js

Tags: javascript, momentjs

Im trying to get the EST date using moment.js but it always gives me the local datetime.

```
var curr_date    = moment.tz(new Date(), "America/New_York");
```

when I execute this command in console, I don't get the NY time.

Comment: It stores a `moment` instance in `curr_date`. For me, when I execute this in console, it returns the object correctly. What do you get if you enter `curr_date.format("HH:mm")` afterwards?

Comment: I'm in Central Time and it gives the central time instead of EST time

Comment: The alert statement gives me the EST time but when I print in console it gives me the actual time(CST).

Comment: this worked...var curr_date = moment.tz(new Date(), "America/New_York");...curr_date.format()

Comment: the _d object that you are seeing in the console does not reflect the actual value of the date contained in moment. Ignore any properties starting with _. Just pay attention to the result of .format()

Comment: You don't need to pass in `new Date()` either.  Just omit that parameter.

Answer (score 3):

I found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35360919/4802228) really helpful. Basically, *stop* using the Date object explicitly.

```
const moment = require('moment-timezone')
const timeInEST = moment().tz('America/New_York').format('MM/DD/YYYY HH:mm')
```